# Activate anaconda and start a webserver from cmd script

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda

I would like to activate Anaconda environment and start a Python server from cmd script.

Currently the script looks like this:

```
cd "C:\Users\usmazuc\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda32\Scripts"
activate my_env
cd "C:\wb"
python web_server.py
```

Script works for the first part - it activates anaconda environment, but it doesn't execute any command which follows `activate my_env`.

Currently I run this script from cmd console, but in the long run I would like to run it as a Windows startup script.

The goal is to:
1) activate anaconda env
2) from within this environment, start the Python server

The whole process shouldn't be visible for the user. The server should be running in the background but the user should not be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch script you should use `call activate my_env`. See https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true.

You can also just use the full path to the environment when you call Python, like `C:\Users\usmazuc\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda32\envs\my_env\python.exe web_server.py`. If you do this, there is no need to use `activate`.